# Does every straight line intersects the graph of $e^x$ ($x\geq 0$)?

Tags: functions

Does every straight line of the form $a\cdot x+b$ with $b>1$ intersects the graph of the function $[0, \infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, $x\longmapsto e^x$?

Comment: does $b$ have to be finite?

Comment: Yes, it must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = e^x - (ax+b)$$
We have
$$f(0) = 1-b < 0 \text{ and }\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$$
Since $f(x)$ is continuous, there exists a point $x^* \in (0,\infty)$, such that $f(x^*) = 0$, which means that there exists $x^* \in (0,\infty)$, such that $$e^{x^*} = ax^*+b$$

Answer (score 2):

$e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \cdots > \dfrac{x^2}{2}$ for $x>0$.

$\dfrac{x^2}{2} \ge ax+b$ for $x\ge a+\sqrt{a^2+2b}=c$.

So, $e^x > ax+b$ for $x\ge c$.

Consider $f(x)=e^x-(ax+b)$. Then $f(0)=1-b <0$ and $f(c)>0$.
Since $f$ is continous, it must have a zero in $(0,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check what happens at $x = 0$ and $x =$ big enough.